# Retrieve step count and sleep data for a flutter based project on Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, healthkit, google-fit, pedometer, flutter-health

I'm working on an application in health & fitness space and one of the requirement is to retrieve activities data (step count and sleep data to begin with) from wearables.

My understanding is that I will be able to get this data from Google Fit and Apple Health. I'm confused on to choose flutter package or to use native libraries with platform specific implementation

Option 1 - Flutter package:

- There is a package called Health (https://pub.dev/packages/health). It is a wrapper built around Google Fit, Health Connect for Android and HealthKit for iOS.
- I'm concerned about the reliability and security of this package as this is not flutter favourite.
- Has anyone used this package here in this community? If yes, please share your feedback.

Option 2 - Native approach:

- Platform specific implementation using method channel to integrate Google Fit API and Apple Health Kit API
- For Android - According to Google Fit documentation, HistoryClient API i.e, to fetch historical fitness data is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient) and have to use Health Connect instead (https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect). Now, Health Connect app is still in beta and both Google Fit and Health Connect will not come pre installed on most of the devices and both these apps are mandatory to retrieve data. Correct me if I'm wrong.
- For iOS - Apple HealthKit integration and implementation in swift for iOS

Please suggest which one would be the better option or any other approach I'm missing..

Answer (score 1):

the Health package is good and you can use it in general. The best solution would be to take steps from the pedometer package(https://pub.dev/packages/pedometer) for Android and Ios, because it will give you real-time data. For sleep data, use Health

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34844911)